Why am I getting cache miss while accessing a variable, only updated by the same thread?
I am trying to measure cache misses in a multi-threaded application using perf_event_open on Linux. The code involves two threads: Thread t1, that updates an aligned integer (x) and another thread t2 that reads from it. However, I am getting cache misses on accessing x with thread t1, even though it is updated by t1 only.
Here is the relevant code snippet:
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <linux/perf_event.h>    /* Definition of PERF_* constants */
#include <linux/hw_breakpoint.h> /* Definition of HW_* constants */
#include <sys/syscall.h>         /* Definition of SYS_* constants */
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <atomic>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>


struct int_aligned {
    alignas(1024) int value;//align to 1024 bytes, to avoid false sharing
    int_aligned(int val) : value(val) {}
};

int_aligned* x;
int_aligned* y;
std::atomic<bool> changed;
int loop_count;
std::vector<int> load_time;


// Executes perf_event_open syscall and makes sure it is succesful or exit
static long perf_event_open(struct perf_event_attr *hw_event, pid_t pid, int cpu, int group_fd, unsigned long flags){
  int fd;
    fd = syscall(SYS_perf_event_open, hw_event, pid, cpu, group_fd, flags);
    if (fd == -1) {
        perror("");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return fd;
}

//calculate performance metrics
void print_performance_metrics(std::vector<int> &numbers, int element_count){
    // Sort the numbers
    std::sort(numbers.begin(), numbers.end());
    // Calculate min and max
    int min = numbers[0];
    int max = numbers[element_count-1]; // numbers[element_count-1] is the last element

    std::cout << "Min: " << min << "\n";
    std::cout << "Max: " << max << "\n";

    // Calculate percentile 
    int percentile_req[] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90};
    int size_per = sizeof(percentile_req) / sizeof(percentile_req[0]);
    int percentile_values[size_per];
    for(int i = 0; i < size_per; i++){
        int index = (percentile_req[i] * element_count) / 100 - 1; // Adjust index for 0-based array
        index = std::max(0, std::min(index, element_count - 1)); // Ensure index is within bounds
        percentile_values[i] = numbers[index];
    }
    std::cout << "Percentile values are: " << "\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < size_per; i++) {
        std::cout << std::setw(10) << percentile_req[i];
    }
    std::cout << "\n";

    // Print the percentile values
    for (int i = 0; i < size_per; i++) {
        std::cout << std::setw(10) << percentile_values[i];
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}

void writer() {
    int cnt = 0;

    int fd;
    long long count;
    struct perf_event_attr pe;
    memset(&pe, 0, sizeof(pe));
    pe.type = PERF_TYPE_HW_CACHE;
    pe.size = sizeof(pe);
    pe.config = (PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_L1D) |
                (PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_OP_READ << 8) |
                (PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_RESULT_MISS << 16);
    pe.disabled = 1;
    pe.exclude_kernel = 1;
    pe.exclude_hv = 1;
    fd = perf_event_open(&pe, 0, -1, -1, 0);
    if (fd == -1) {
        std::cerr << "Error opening leader " << std::hex << pe.config << std::dec << "\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_RESET, 0);
    ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_ENABLE, 0);
    while(cnt < loop_count) {
        if(!changed.load()) {
            auto x_ptr = x;
            ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_RESET, 0);
            ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_ENABLE, 0);
            auto x_copy = x_ptr->value; //getting cache miss here
            ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_DISABLE, 0);
            x_copy++;
            x->value = x_copy;
            read(fd, &count, sizeof(long long));
            load_time.push_back(count);
            cnt++; // Increment the counter to ensure the loop progresses
            changed.store(true);
        }
    }
    close(fd); // Ensure the file descriptor is closed after the loop
}

void reader() {
    int cnt = 0;
    while(cnt < loop_count) {
        if(changed.load()) {
            volatile auto  x_copy = x->value;
            y->value = x->value;
            cnt++;
            changed.store(false);
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    x = new int_aligned(0);
    y = new int_aligned(0);
    changed.store(false);
    loop_count = atoi(argv[1]);
    std::thread t1(writer);
    std::thread t2(reader);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    std::cout << "x: " << x->value << "\n";
    std::cout << "y: " << y->value << "\n";
    print_performance_metrics(load_time, load_time.size());
    return 0;
}


I compile the code with the following command:
g++ <filename> -o <out> -std=c++17 -pthread -O2

And I run it with appropriate permissions for perf:
echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/perf_event_paranoid

The issue is that I am consistently getting cache misses when loading x in the writer thread, even though x is aligned to 1024 bytes and should not suffer from false sharing. x is only updated by the writer thread, so I don't understand why there are cache misses.
Any insights into why this is happening and how I can resolve it would be greatly appreciated.

Another thread reading a variable means the writer core loses exclusive ownership (it transition from MESI  Modified state to Shared (or Forwarded or Owned for MESIF or MOESI).  So the writer needs to do another Read-for-Ownership (RFO) or invalidate to get exclusive ownership again.  So you'd expect store misses.  But that wouldn't explain load misses if the writer is also reading the variable it's updating, which is apparently what you're measuring.  I wouldn't expect the cache line to become unreadable during the RFO.
